# mysql how to get maximum set length of each column

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an HTML form that I need to get the maximum set length of each of my fields in the corresponding MySQL database to set a proper value for the maxlength attribute of my text fields.  Is there a MySQL query that will give me those set maximum field lengths?

The best solution I have is to query `SHOW COLUMNS FROM {database name}`, but that will return the field type with the maximum field length in parentheses (e.g. int(6), varchar(20), decimal(5,1), etc.), so then I would to use PHP or something to filter out only the maximum lengths, and there just seems like there's got to be a better way.

Comment: Nope, you cracked the code.

Comment: I'm not sure the reason you need a query to get max length when you can hard code it in your markup?

Comment: A schema shouldn't really change that often where you would need to make dynamic responsive code like this (which parses the schema every time it needs to render a page). You would be better off just defining them in a common config, so its in one place to change if need be. Less overhead.

Comment: @Randall Not trying to change the schema, only trying to get the already set maximum lengths of the database fields. My forms without a maxlength attr in the text fields make it easy to produce an error from attempting to submit values to the database that exceed the maximum set length of the column.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Because if I can get the data dynamically, that's one less thing I need to do. If the data can be provided by the SHOW COLUMNS query, it seems logical to me that if the database will give out that data that it could do it in an actual more useable way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear why you need this. Don't you know which table & column you're inserted data into?

Anyway, here's a query that can tell you the length of the longest VARCHAR in all tables in a given database:

```
SELECT MAX(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH) AS MAX_LENGTH
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA='mydatabase'
```

If you need to know the length of *each* column:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA='mydatabase'
```

You might like to refer to the reference docs here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html

---

Re: your comment:

Sure, that makes sense. But there's a bit of overhead to any database query, including the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. If you don't have to run an extra query to get this metadata, that would be better.

Many app frameworks keep metadata about the schema and tables in config files of some type. XML, YAML, JSON, etc. This duplicates what is stored in the database, but it's generally quicker to access it.

I was one of the developers of Zend Framework 1.0 framework, years ago. The Zend_Db_Table class did query the database to get columns, data types, etc. but it turned out that querying the INFORMATION_SCHEMA so frequently made apps way too slow. So we [implemented an optional cache component that you could plug into the Zend_Db_Table object](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.metadata.caching), and it would allow the table to "remember" its metadata from one PHP request to the next.

Comment: To answer your question on "why I need this:" I was hoping that as long I was dynamically filling in text fields with their current values in a database row that I could also fill in the maxlength attribute in the text fields.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Bill Karwin.  Great information.  Is there a reason CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH returns null for data types like "int" and "decimal"?

Comment: INT and DECIMAL are not string types.

Comment: The question asker should accept this answer, because it provides a way to do it, and a good bit of information about why you shouldn't do it. Either way, its a good answer.

Comment: @BillKarwin So basically only the string data type has a character length associated with it.  I didn't know this was the case; thanks.